# Correlation function in relaxation in NMR

Tags: quantum-mechanics, spectroscopy, nuclear-magnetic-resonance

I am new in this community, I am from a chemistry background.  I want to know a detailed solution of a density matrix for a singlet state using the concept of spin lattice relaxation in [NMR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_magnetic_resonance).  I will be happy if anyone can explain in detail or give some references.